# Undefined symbol in protoc with gcc 11 build

Tags: c++, gcc, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to build protocol-buffer by following [these instructions.](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/master/src/README.md)

This is what I did.

```
git clone https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf.git
cd protobuf
git submodule update --init --recursive
./autogen.sh
./configure
make -j6
```

After the successful build, I checked

```
ldd -d src/.libs/protoc
```

It showed a lot of undefined symbols.

```
root@renju-mc:~/.../protobuf# ldd -d src/.libs/protoc
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff1f3a5000)
        libprotoc.so.28 => not found
        libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007fdce230c000)
        libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007fdce20f4000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fdce1d03000)
        libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007fdce1965000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fdce291d000)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8compiler20CommandLineInterface12AllowPluginsERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEE       (src/.libs/protoc)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8compiler20CommandLineInterface3RunEiPKPKc (src/.libs/protoc)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8compiler20CommandLineInterfaceD1Ev        (src/.libs/protoc)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8compiler6csharp9GeneratorC1Ev     (src/.libs/protoc)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8compiler6python9GeneratorC1Ev     (src/.libs/protoc)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8compiler20CommandLineInterface17RegisterGeneratorERKNSt7__cxx1112basic_stringIcSt11char_traitsIcESaIcEEESA_PNS1_13CodeGeneratorESA_   (src/.libs/protoc)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8compiler20CommandLineInterfaceC1Ev        (src/.libs/protoc)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8compiler4java13JavaGeneratorD1Ev  (src/.libs/protoc)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8compiler13CodeGeneratorD2Ev       (src/.libs/protoc)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8compiler4java15KotlinGeneratorC1Ev        (src/.libs/protoc)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8compiler6csharp9GeneratorD1Ev     (src/.libs/protoc)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8compiler3cpp12CppGeneratorD1Ev    (src/.libs/protoc)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8compiler10objectivec19ObjectiveCGeneratorC1Ev     (src/.libs/protoc)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8compiler4java15KotlinGeneratorD1Ev        (src/.libs/protoc)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8compiler10objectivec19ObjectiveCGeneratorD1Ev     (src/.libs/protoc)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8compiler3cpp12CppGeneratorC1Ev    (src/.libs/protoc)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8compiler4java13JavaGeneratorC1Ev  (src/.libs/protoc)
undefined symbol: _ZN6google8protobuf8compiler6python9GeneratorD1Ev     (src/.libs/protoc)
```

`libprotoc.so.28 => not found` this file is present at the same location as of protoc.

```
root@renju-mc:~/.../protobuf# ls -l src/.libs/libprotoc.so.28
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 19 Jul 25 22:20 src/.libs/libprotoc.so.28 -> libprotoc.so.28.0.3
```

I'm using Ubuntu 18.04, with gcc-11.

```
gcc version 11.1.0 (Ubuntu 11.1.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Linux loader, `ld.so` does not, by default, load libraries from the current directory but only from predefined locations.

You are attempting to load a library from the current directory that depends on another library in the current directory, hence the load failure.

`ld.so`'s manual page explains [how to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in order change this behavior](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/ld.so.8.html).

Answer (score 1):

It will probably work better if you follow all the instructions including the step "make install". Usually "make install" places built dynamic libraries in some standard location like /usr/local/lib where the dynamic linker will find them.

If you for some reason do not want to install the software you can use the environment variable LD_LIBRARY_PATH to point out your non standard directory containing dynamic libraries. Example:
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=src/.libs